# Django display data from json

Tags: json, django, model, fetch

i want to display cryptocurrency prices on my site. Therefor i parse the latest BTC/USD price from coinmarketcap.com
now i want to display them in a list but i first dont know who to save the symbol from the json to my database and second how can i display my view propperly. Currently i only save key:value of price_usd where key is the name of the currency.

views.py

```
def crypto_ticker(request):
        list_prices = CryptoPrices.objects.get_queryset().order_by('-pk')
        paginator = Paginator(list_prices, 100)  # Show 100 prices per page
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        price = paginator.get_page(page)
        return render(request, 'MyProject/crypto_ticker.html', {'price': price})
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^crypto_ticker/$', MyProject_views.crypto_ticker, name='crypto_ticker'),
```

models.py

```
class CryptoPrices(models.Model):
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

celery update task:

```
@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(minute='*/1')), name="Update Crypto rate(s)", ignore_result=True)
def get_exchange_rate():
    api_url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=100"
    try:
        exchange_rates = requests.get(api_url).json()
        for exchange_rate in exchange_rates:
            CryptoPrices.objects.update_or_create(key=exchange_rate['id'],
                                                  defaults={'value': round(float(exchange_rate['price_usd']), 3)}
                                                  )
        logger.info("Exchange rate(s) updated successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely just adding

```
symbol= exchange_rate['symbol']
```

to your update_or_create will work?
The JSON from coinmarketcap sets that as a key in the dictionary, unless you want an image that they use?
In that case you would have to save copies of that image yourself, create a mapping from the text of the symbol to the image itself, and format that on your html output.